# Function defined twice

Tags: bash, function

If you define a function several times in a bash script will the last definition always take precedence?
Suppose you source the following script and then call `glub`, will the lastly defined `glub` be executed? Is this written somewhere in the official documentation?

```
glub() {
  echo Hi
}

glub() {
  echo Hello
}
```

I assume the same logic applies to variables/parameters.

Comment: last definition or last value

Comment: @anubhava Link to documentation would be great :)

Comment: Hope this helps: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html